# Email sheduler functionality create in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

In my application want to add functionality email sheduler
In this email send automatically as per time set by user 
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

No, I guess that's not possible using any of the apple frameworks.

**Alternative**

You can use Some web service when user set email Scheduler , and now from server side you can send email to user.

Comment: It is possible date and time from datepicker  set and that match with system date and time than email will be send

Comment: Sorry didnt get you, please explain properly. :)

Comment: Using datepicker store date and time into sqlite database  and compare database date time field with system current date and time

Comment: Another thing i want to ask

Comment: @binitmodi: Now what?